# Android MediaPlayer Streaming setDataSource FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Tags: android, firebase, stream, android-mediaplayer, filenotfoundexception

I want to stream mp3 via firebase and mediaplayer. I am holding my musics in firebase storage and passing their downloadUrl to my mediaplayer instance. I am listing all songs and select one of them and start playing but when after selected song finish, it gives an error

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Called when the service is being created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Service Demo", "Service Created");

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
}

// to initialize the media class
public void initMusicPlayer() {

    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.i("TEST", "Service, song end");
    playNext();
}

public void playSong() {
    //play a song
    player.reset();

    String songUrl = mCurrentPlayList.get(mCurrentSongPos).getSongUrl();

    try {
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songUrl));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }

    player.prepareAsync();
}

// Skip to next song
public void playNext(){
    if(checkConnection()) {
        mCurrentSongPos++;
        if (mCurrentSongPos >= mCurrentPlayList.size()) {
            mCurrentSongPos = 0;
        }
        playSong();
        Log.i("TEST", "Next Song is playing");
    }
}

// Back to previsous song
public void playPrev(){
    if(checkConnection()) {
        mCurrentSongPos--;
        if (mCurrentSongPos < 0) {
            mCurrentSongPos = mCurrentPlayList.size() - 1;
        }
        playSong();
        Log.i("TEST", "Previous Song is playing");
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
                                                                  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/masalzamani-60c94.appspot.com/o/Songs%2FEzop%20Masallar%C4%B1%2FEzop%20Masallar%C4%B1%203%20-%20Aslan%20Postu%20Giyen%20E%C5%9Fek.mp3?alt=media&token=4c298a8f-7bb0-4cbc-8c82-82ccc51c24a7
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1074)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:927)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:854)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1085)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.playSong(LocalService.java:303)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.playNext(LocalService.java:477)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.onCompletion(LocalService.java:232)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3346)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
06-17 18:27:06.841 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
06-17 18:27:06.861 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-17 18:27:06.861 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync
06-17 18:27:06.866 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/row_music_icon.png
06-17 18:27:06.881 29201-29214/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 18:27:06.921 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/TEST: Next Song is playing
06-17 18:27:07.451 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
06-17 18:27:07.776 29201-29214/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize is 5179086
06-17 18:27:07.786 29201-29217/ysfcyln.masalzamani D/MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeOut =  30000ms
06-17 18:27:08.451 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
06-17 18:27:08.591 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=15, ext2=0
06-17 18:27:08.591 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: buffering 15
06-17 18:27:08.591 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: callback application
06-17 18:27:08.591 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: getDuration_l
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: callback application
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (973, 0)
06-17 18:27:08.596 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: callback application
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getDuration: 0 (msec)
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: prepared
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: callback application
06-17 18:27:08.601 29201-29218/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-17 18:27:08.611 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
06-17 18:27:08.611 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/TEST: Service, song end
06-17 18:27:08.646 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer-JNI: reset
06-17 18:27:08.646 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: reset
06-17 18:27:08.646 29201-30675/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-17 18:27:08.666 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
                                                                  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/masalzamani-60c94.appspot.com/o/Songs%2FEzop%20Masallar%C4%B1%2FEzop%20Masallar%C4%B1%204%20-%20Aslan%2C%20Kurt%20ve%20Tilki.mp3?alt=media&token=8da077ee-bad5-4688-9833-caf8e15daf05
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1074)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:927)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:854)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1085)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.playSong(LocalService.java:303)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.playNext(LocalService.java:477)
                                                                      at ysfcyln.masalzamani.LocalService.onCompletion(LocalService.java:232)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3478)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
06-17 18:27:08.666 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
06-17 18:27:08.666 29201-30675/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
06-17 18:27:08.671 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-17 18:27:08.671 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync
06-17 18:27:08.676 29201-29214/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 18:27:08.681 29201-29214/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
06-17 18:27:08.686 29201-29201/ysfcyln.masalzamani I/TEST: Next Song is playing
```

it gives same error when first song selected but it plays successfully, I don't figured out why other songs are not playing, can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its common bug of mediaplayer. When I switch media player with ExoPlayer, everything works well

For anyone have the same error, ı am sharing the basic usage of ExoPlayer

Add ExoPlayer

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.2'
```

Then

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExoPlayer.EventListener{

private BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
private TrackSelector trackSelector;
private TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
private ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;
private DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter;
private MediaSource mediaSource;

private String songUrl = "http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/edvard-grieg-peer-gynt1-morning-mood-piano.mp3";

private Button stopButton;
private Button startButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);

    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"),defaultBandwidthMeter);


    mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(songUrl),
            dataSourceFactory,
            extractorsFactory,
            null,
            null);

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,trackSelector);

    player.addListener(this);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);

    Log.v("TEST","playing state : " + player.getPlaybackState());

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
}


@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
    Log.i("TEST", "onLoadingChanged: " + isLoading + "");
    Log.i("TEST", "Buffered Position: " + player.getBufferedPosition() + "");
    Log.i("TEST", "Buffered Percentage: " + player.getBufferedPercentage() + "");
}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

    if(playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY){
        Log.i("TEST", "ExoPlayer State is: READY");
    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING){
        Log.i("TEST", "ExoPlayer State is: BUFFERING");
    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED){
        Log.i("TEST", "ExoPlayer State is: ENDED");
    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE){
        Log.i("TEST", "ExoPlayer State is: IDLE");
    }


}

@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

}

@Override
public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of `getApplicationContext()` in the `player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songUrl));` call makes the `MediaPlayer` look locally *first* (because of the specified application context), then try the network when it doesn't find it.

The following overload appears to avoid that:

```
player.setDataSource(songUrl);
```